# list click event is not trigger after clicking the back button on ionic2 ios device

Tags: ios, angular, ionic2

i have used following code

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar>
        <button ion-button menuToggle>
            <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
        </button>
        <ion-title>
            <span>{{ title }}</span>
        </ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>


<button class="action-button getstarted" ion-button clear small  (click)="goToFeed(id)">Already Purchased</button>
```

Button click action

```
//Goto feed page with arg
    goToFeed(post: any) {
        this.nav.push(FeedPage, {
            postId:post
        });
    }
```

when click from back button,the button click does not trigger as first time,please any idea

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: are you getting any error

Comment: i am not getting any error.but i need to click twice time

Comment: you want two time to tap the button then only you want to invoke the funtion correct

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39628718/ionic2-tap-vs-click