# Like reaction in each element in ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I am using ionic 3, and looping ion-card with like using ngFor. I want to know how can I react with the user when user click the like/unlike button in each ion-card without reload the list.

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let u of users">
   <p>{{u.name}}</p>
   <button ion-button [hidden]="u.isliked=='1'" (click)="like(u.id)">like</button>
   <button ion-button [hidden]="u.isliked!='1'" (click)="unlike(u.id)">unlike</button>
</ion-card>
```

Comment: What isn't working in your current code? Or if this code works fine, how do you want to 'react with the user'?

Comment: @Ivaro18 I can like/unlike, but when I click like button, i need to change to unlike button. If click unlike button, need to change to like button, How can I do this without reload the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of the `*ngIf` operator. This won't hide the element like the `hidden` property, but actually removes the element from the DOM.

(made `u.isLiked` into a `boolean` because I think it's cleaner that way, personal preference. Also changed `(click)` to `(tap)`, see the answer on [ionic2 tap vs click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39628718/ionic2-tap-vs-click/39632430#39632430) for more details.)

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let u of users">
   <p>{{u.name}}</p>
   <button ion-button *ngIf="u.isLiked" (tap)="like(u.id)">like</button>
   <button ion-button *ngIf="!u.isliked" (tap)="unlike(u.id)">unlike</button>
</ion-card>
```

And in your ts:

```
like(userId) {
  for(let user of this.users) {
    if(user.id == userId) {
        user.isLiked = true;
      }
   }
}

unlike(userId) {
  for(let user of this.users) {
    if(user.id == userId) {
      user.isLiked = false;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: if users array is very large, will the for loop become a bottle neck?

Comment: You could use `.filter` or another function but the for loop is the fastest way. See https://jsperf.com/extract-props/1

Comment: But I'd recommend against loading a very large list of users, you might want to check out ionic's infinite scroll and retrieve your users as a fragmented list.