# My Wishlisted product is not showing Wishlisted for the login user in Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4

I am working on the Ionic Ecommerce App and It has a Wishlist button for all the products. The user can only wishlist the product after login and if the user is not login it will the user a popup message. But the problem is that when the user wishlist the product by clicking on the heart and again the user will come on the product page and wishlist product is not showing the product wish-listed.

This is my **productdetails.html**:

```
<ion-col *ngFor="let product of this.pdeta" col-5 class="mynewcol22">
<button ion-button icon-only class="wish-list-btn card" (click)="toggleOnWishlist(product)" color="light" class="mywisbtn11">
    <ion-icon [name]="product.onWishlist ? 'ios-heart' : 'heart-outline' "></ion-icon>
</button>
</ion-col>
```

In this view, I am showing the wishlist button as a heart-outline.

This is my **productdetails.ts**:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, ToastController, AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { CartProvider } from '../../providers/cart/cart';
import { CartPage } from '../cart/cart';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import { WishlistPage } from '../wishlist/wishlist';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-productdetails',
  templateUrl: 'productdetails.html',
})
export class ProductdetailsPage {
  detailsp: any = [];
  pdeta: any = [];
  items: Object[] = [];
  itemsInCart: Object[] = [];
  selectProduct: any;
  totalPrice: any;
  productCount: number = 1;
  SelectedSize:any;
  cartItems: any[];
  noproducts: boolean = false;
  nosize: boolean = true;
  isenabled: boolean = false;
  hassizenot: boolean = false;
  hassize:boolean = true;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private cartService: CartProvider, public toastCtrl: ToastController, private storage: Storage, private alertCtrl: AlertController) {
  this.detailsp = this.navParams.get('productdet'); <!-- I am getting the Products -->
  this.pdeta = this.detailsp.msg;
  }

  toggleOnWishlist(product){
    this.storage.get("ID").then((val) =>
    {
      if(val)
      {
       product.onWishlist = !product.onWishlist;
       console.log(product);
       this.cartService.addToWishlist(product).then((val) => {
        this.presentWishToast(product.product_name);
      });
      }
      else
      {
        this.presentAlert();
      }
    });
  }

  presentWishToast(name: any) {
    let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
      message: `${name} has been added to wishlist`,
      showCloseButton: true,
      closeButtonText: 'View Wishlist'
    });

    toast.onDidDismiss(() => {
      this.navCtrl.push(WishlistPage);
    });
    toast.present();
  }

  presentAlert() {
    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: 'Please Login For Wishlist',
      buttons: ['Dismiss']
    });
    alert.present();
  }

  toggleOnSize(psize){
    psize.onSize = !psize.onSize;
  }

}
```

In this ts file, If the user is not login it will show the popup message and if the user is login it can wishlist the product. But the problem is that after wishlist the product and when the user will come to that product, the product is not showing the wishlisted. Like in the image one product is wishlist and the other is not but when the user will come to that wishlist product, it is not showing the product wishlisted. Any help is much appreciated.

This is my **wishlist.ts**:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, LoadingController, AlertController, ToastController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { CartProvider } from "../../providers/cart/cart";
import { CartPage } from '../cart/cart';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-wishlist',
  templateUrl: 'wishlist.html',
})
export class WishlistPage {
  wishItems: any[] = [];
  isCartItemLoaded: boolean = false;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private cartService: CartProvider, public loadingCtrl: LoadingController, private alertCtrl: AlertController, public toastCtrl: ToastController) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad WishlistPage');
    this.loadWishItems();
  }

  loadWishItems() {
    let loader = this.loadingCtrl.create({
      content: "Wait.."
    });
    loader.present();
    this.cartService
      .getWishItems()
      .then(val => {
        this.wishItems = val;
        //console.log(val);
        this.isCartItemLoaded = true;
        loader.dismiss();
      })
      .catch(err => {});
  }

  removeWishItem(itm)
  {
    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: 'Remove Product',
      message: 'Do you want to remove this product?',
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Cancel',
          role: 'cancel',
          handler: () => {
            //console.log('Cancel Clicked');
          }
        },
        {
          text: 'Yes',
          handler: () => {
            this.cartService.removeFromWish(itm).then(() => {
              this.loadWishItems();
            });
          }
        }
      ]
    });
    alert.present();
  }

  WishItemToCart(itm)
  {
     //console.log(itm);
     var productPrice = parseInt(itm.product_actual_price);
     let cartProduct = {
      product_id: itm.id,
      name: itm.product_name,
      image: itm.image,
      count: itm.count,
      disprice: itm.product_price,
      discountp: itm.discount,
      productPrice: parseInt(itm.product_actual_price),
      totalPrice: productPrice,
    };
     this.cartService.addToCart(cartProduct).then((val) => {
      this.presentToast(cartProduct.name);
    });
    this.removeWishItem2(itm);
  }

  removeWishItem2(itm)
  {
    this.cartService.removeFromWish(itm).then(() => {
      this.loadWishItems();
    });
  }

  presentToast(name: any) {
    let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
      message: `${name} has been added to cart`,
      showCloseButton: true,
      closeButtonText: 'View Cart'
    });

    toast.onDidDismiss(() => {
      this.navCtrl.push(CartPage);
    });
    toast.present();
  }
}
```

This is my Cart Service: **providers>cart>cart.ts**:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

const WISH_KEY = 'wishItems';

@Injectable()
export class CartProvider {

  constructor(public http: HttpClient, public storage: Storage) {
    console.log('Hello CartProvider Provider');
  }

  addToWishlist(productwishdet) {
    return this.getWishItems().then(result => {
      if (result) {
        if (!this.containsObject(productwishdet, result)) {
          result.push(productwishdet);
          return this.storage.set(WISH_KEY, result);
        } else {
          result.push(productwishdet);
          return this.storage.set(WISH_KEY, result);
        }

      } else {
        return this.storage.set(WISH_KEY, [productwishdet]);
      }
    })
  }

  removeFromWish(productdet) {
    return this.getWishItems().then(result => {
      if (result && result.length) {
        const newList = result.filter(el => el.id !== productdet.id);
        return this.storage.set(WISH_KEY, newList);
      }
    })
}

  getWishItems() {
    return this.storage.get(WISH_KEY);
  }
}
```

[image]

For Reference: [Like reaction in each element in ionic 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50602541/like-reaction-in-each-element-in-ionic-3)

Comment: are you only writing on storage? I don't see you reading the value on init

Comment: @RicardoVallejo. I have used the storage to store the user id after login.

Comment: @RicardoVallejo. Can you please suggest reading the value on init?

Comment: What I meant was, when you are populating your items list, make sure you set the attribute onWishlist for each item

Comment: @RicardoVallejo. Can you please do the code?

Comment: @RicardoVallejo. Can you please suggest the code for setting the attribute onWishlist for each item.

Comment: @RicardoVallejo. So can you please help me with the code?

Comment: if user not logged in into app and direct click on like button you show alert and your unlike button become like right ?

Comment: @CodeChanger. Yes. So, Can you please help me one more time. Its a request.

Comment: `this.users` is your product array ?

Comment: Yes. It is an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
toggleOnWishlist(product) {
    this.storage.get("ID").then(val => {
      if (val) {
        if (!product.onWishlist) {
          this.cartService.addToWishlist(product).then(val => {
            this.presentWishToast(product.product_name);
          });
        } else {
          this.cartService.removeFromWish(product).then(val => {
            this.presentWishToast(product.product_name);
          });
        }
        product.onWishlist = !product.onWishlist;
      } else {

        //Add forcefully unlike
        product.onWishlist = false;
        this.presentAlert();
      }
    });
  }
```

Try to assign `false` for non logged in users.

**Edit**

```
getproducts($id)
{
          //console.log($id);
          this.restProvider.getproductdetails($id)
          .then(data => {
               updateProductListBasedOnWishList(data);
          });
}

updateProductListBasedOnWishList(products){

    this.cartService
      .getWishItems()
      .then(val => {
        this.wishItems = val;
        products = products.map(item => {
          let item2 = this.wishItems.find(i2 => i2.id === item.id);
          return item2 ? { ...item, ...item2 } : item;
        });

        this.users = products;

        this.navCtrl.push(ProductdetailsPage,
          {
            productdet : this.users,
          });
        });

      })
      .catch(err => {});


  }
```

Hope this will helps.

Comment: If the user is not login, it wont be able to like and it will show the error. That's why I have used this .this.storage.get("ID"), If the user ID exists then after it can like. Bu the problem is that, when the logged In user like and after some time, it will visit the page then it should show the like.

Comment: The problem is that, when the logged In user click on heart button and it will fill the heart button but when the user again visit the product the heart should show filled.

Comment: as you are storing wish list locally every time when user come to this page you need to compare wish list with product list and enable flag for wish listed products

Comment: from where u get product list ? from storage ?

Comment: I am getting the products from the Api made in laravel.

Comment: so you want this wishlist only locally or also on api server side ?

Comment: This wishlist locally on App.

Comment: Okay. Can this be solution like when the user clicks on like, it will store until it is unlike.

Comment: Can you please add code to fetch product list ? and HTML also ?

Comment: please add above updateProduct method after getting product data from api.

Comment: I don't have this function in my service. getWishItems

Comment: so add cart service and call same like wishlist.ts

Comment: share your updated code or update question so I can help you on that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187301/discussion-between-raghav-and-codechanger).