# How to do on-touch in Ionic 4?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular6, ionic4

I am upgrading an AngularJS/Ionic 1 app to Angular 6/Ionic 4. And in one of my old modules I am using [on-touch](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/api/directive/onTouch/), however I have been unable to find anything similar in Ionic 4, could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Does `tap` not work?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your question, can you please reproduce your  question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(tap) or (click) is probably what you're looking for.

Here is a post describing the differences.
[ionic2 tap vs click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39628718/ionic2-tap-vs-click)

Answer (score 0):

with ionic 4 you only have gestures like (tap) / (click) / (pan) / (Swipe) so touch can either be (tap) or (click).